# Method not found: 'System.Data.IDbCommand NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.get_CurrentCommand()'

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to commit transaction using Nhibernate (.net).

After I update the model and commit I got following error at  transaction.Commit (); :

Method not found: 'System.Data.IDbCommand NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.get_CurrentCommand()'.

My code is :

```
  session.Update(model);
  transaction.Commit ();
  session.Flush();
  session.Close();
```

Comment: I am getting the same error after migrating from NH3.3 to 5.1.3. Any advice out there?

Comment: what version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.0, are you able to fix this ?

Comment: I posted a question on this as well. Here it is, with the answer in my context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467505/migrating-nhibernate-3-3-to-5-getting-method-not-found-system-data-idbcommand