# Migrating NHibernate 3.3 to 5, getting Method not found: System.Data.IDbCommand NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.get_CurrentCommand() with SqlAzure

Tags: nhibernate, azure-sql-database

I am busy migrating a project from NHibernate 3.3.3.4 to 5.1.3. I have picked up an error when committing a transaction or flushing the session.

The error I am currently receiving is as follows:

```
Method not found: 'System.Data.IDbCommand NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.get_CurrentCommand()'.
```

I have looked into the NHibernate 5.1.3 code and release notes and I can see that there has been a change to the `CurrentCommand` property getter for the `AbstractBacther` class. In this major release of NHibernate, this property has changed from being of type `IDbCommand` to type `DbCommand`. See the difference below:

**Version 3.3.x** [Permalink](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/e955740e5eb1982f4f0b33337792d8e5b18d8553/src/NHibernate/AdoNet/AbstractBatcher.cs#L65)

```
protected IDbCommand CurrentCommand
{
    get { return _batchCommand; }
}
```

**Version 5.1.3** [Permalink](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/8649f9ac52cfc0d022a9553f41a860873a0d1450/src/NHibernate/AdoNet/AbstractBatcher.cs#L65)

```
protected DbCommand CurrentCommand
{
    get { return _batchCommand; }
}
```

I am using the SqlAzureClientDriver (NHibernate.SqlAzure) for reliable SQL Azure connections. I have noticed that the latest version of [NHibernate.SqlAzure](https://github.com/MRCollective/NHibernate.SqlAzure) is still using the IDbCommand implementation.

Has anybody else using **SqlAzureClientDriver** experienced this problem and been able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NHibernate5 version of SqlAzureClientDriver which can be installed as the nuget package NHibernate5.SqlAzure.

Comment: Thanks BruceM. Worked like a charm!